# Entity Framework Include fails to compile 

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

I generated my entities via the `DbContext` generator, and added it to an API controller that uses my entities context model. The following method fails to compile though:

```
public IEnumerable<casino> Getcasinos()
    {
        var casinos = db.casinos.Include(c => c.city).Include(c => c.state);
        return casinos.AsEnumerable();
    }
```

The compiler says:

```
Cannot Convert Lambda Expression to Type 'String' Because It Is Not A Delegate Type
```

Any ideas why it is saying this? I have the `System.Linq` namespace imported.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This actually happens because of the `ObjectQuery(T).Include` method. This has the function signature:

```
public ObjectQuery<T> Include(string path);
```

The reason why you're seeing that is probably because wherever you're calling it does not have the `System.Data.Entity` namespace available. From the `DbExtensions` metadata you can see that the `Include` using an expression requires the `System.Data.Entity` namespace:

```
namespace System.Data.Entity
{
    [SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Naming", "CA1709:IdentifiersShouldBeCasedCorrectly", Justification = "Casing is intentional")]
    public static class DbExtensions
    {
        public static IQueryable<T> Include<T, TProperty>(this IQueryable<T> source, Expression<Func<T, TProperty>> path) where T : class;
        public static IQueryable<T> Include<T>(this IQueryable<T> source, string path) where T : class;
        public static IQueryable Include(this IQueryable source, string path);
    }
}
```

If you include the `System.Data.Entity` namespace, the error will resolve.

Comment: @JuniperAsh: No problem. This is actually a very easy mistake to make if you wrap up your data access in a separate layer.